# Свобода и воля. О разнице оттенков

Tags: лексика

Хотелось бы услышать мнение специалистов о разнице оттенков смысла слов "свобода" и "воля". Это — предложение порассуждать самим.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Оба слова многозначные. В каких-то значениях совпадают. Кроме того, свобода- это и философский термин. НАверняка, не одно определение есть. Так что -  что с  чем сравнивать, какое значение Вас интересует? Напишите конкретные примеры. А так - перепечатывать длинные словарные статьи??? Кстати, в языке еще и два слова воля (омонимы)

Comment: Вообще-то, было предложено порассуждать самим. Или без словарных статей - никак?)))

Comment: Ой, к сожалению никак. Не философ я. В конкретных предложениях с вопросом, какое слово лучше употребить - могла бы посмотреть. НЕ более. Моя вина - вопрос до конца не прочитала.

Answer (score 1):

Свобода - это вещь объективная. Свобода - это отсутствие ограничений в обществе. Так как свобода - вещь общественная, то она может быть обществом же и ограничена, вплоть до полного лишения этой свободы. Наличие свободы не означает, что ей обязательно будут пользоваться, все россияне имеют право на свободу передвижения, но многие не отдалялись от своего места жительства дальше сотни километров.

Воля - это вещь субъективная. Воля - это действия в соответствии с собственными желаниями. Так как воля является проявлением личности, а не социума, ограничить волю невозможно, но можно воли лишить, ограничив возможности проявления личности.